# 2D plot using imshow - Nonlinear Schrödinger equation in 2+1 dimensions

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, physics, imshow

I have been working on a physical problem involving the Nonlinear Schrödinger equation in 2+1 dimensions. I want to plot the density which depends on x and y for the last time step of my simulation. The data corresponding to this simulation can be found in [this h5 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11j7AIuTx9qm0ZnIuvasY5C5rlGOoRnt2/view?usp=sharing).

I have written the following script for the plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5

data = h5.File('groundstate_interacting_2D_n50u2.h5', 'r') 
dens = data['1']['norm_dens'] 
norma = data['2']['norm'] 
en_pot = data['3']['energyp'] 
en_kin = data['4']['energyk'] 
en_int = data['5']['energyint'] 
pot_chem = data['6']['potencialchem'] 
latticex = data['7']['x'] 
latticey = data['7']['y'] 
time    = data['7']['t']  
phireal = data['7']['phireal'] 
phiimag = data['7']['phiimag'] 

#computes the square of the module of the wave-function
distr = np.power(phireal[:,:,:],2) + np.power(phiimag[:,:,:],2) 

X, Y = np.meshgrid(latticex, latticey)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mdr = ax.imshow(distr[400,:,:], interpolation='gaussian',cmap='plasma')
ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.grid(False)
fig.colorbar(mdr)

plt.show()
```

In my problem, x and y are both defined in the range (-4.0, 4.0) in lattices (`latticex and latticey`) containing 32 points. I wonder if it is possible to have the same range displayed in my plot. I have tried some things but none of them worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using the `norm` parameter of `imshow`, you can use `vmin` and `vmax` to specify the upper and lower bounds of the colormap. An example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.outer(np.linspace(-10, 10, 100), np.linspace(-10, 10, 100))
a = (a / a.max() - 0.5) * 5.0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
m = ax.imshow(a, cmap='plasma', vmin=-4.0, vmax=4.0)
plt.show()
```

Without `vmin` and `vmax`:

[image]

With `vmin` and `vmax`:

[image]

And this will be reflected in the colorbars, though I have neglected them for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @WilliamMiller. I tried your example but there is still something I want to understand and that is how I change the range displayed in x and y in my plot. In my plot, it automatically sets x and y from 0 to 30. In yours, I ran it here and it's been displayed x and y from 0 to 100. In my case, I would like to have x and y from -4 to 4. Can this be done?

Comment: @HeitorGalacian Certainly, the only question is whether you want to modify the data to actually convert it into the (-4,4) space or if simply changing the limits displayed on the plot is sufficient?

Comment: Yes @William. What I want is to modify to data in order to convert it to the (-4,4) space and make the plot.

Comment: @HeitorGalacian The easiest way to do that would be to normalize the layer of `distr`, then shift by `0.5` and scale by `8`, similar to what I've done for `a` above. Something like `norm_distr = (distr[400,:,:] / (distr[400,0,:].max() - distr[400,0,:].min()) - 0.5) * 8` - but be forewarned, this is not a full spatial transformation and normalizes based on the second axis of `distr`; no guarantees for rectangular layers.